# Installing Javabridge With Pip Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, subprocess, libraries

I'm trying to install the microscoper library and I've gotten everything to work except its javabridge dependency which I have had trouble installing. Everytime I try to install javabridge on its own I get the following error message:

```
C:\>pip install javabridge
Collecting javabridge  
Using cached javabridge-1.0.15.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\<My Username Abbrv>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-s902jjra\javabridge\setup.py", line 393, in <module>
    ext_modules=ext_modules(),
  File "C:\Users\<My Username Abbrv>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-s902jjra\javabridge\setup.py", line 114, in ext_modules
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
  File "c:\users\<My Username>\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\users\<My Username>\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\<My Username Abbrv>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-s902jjra\javabridge\
```

If anyone had any advice on how I could fix this and install the javabridge dependency I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

`setup.py` cannot run [gendef](https://github.com/LeeKamentsky/python-javabridge/blob/master/setup.py#L113) from MinGW. Perhaps it's not in the PATH. Add MinGW directories to PATH and retry.

Comment: This worked unfortunately now I'm getting another error! Thank you though for helping me get closer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these commands, this helped solve my problem for this error.

```
set MSSdk=1
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
pip install javabridge
```