# Problems Installing Javabridge with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, subprocess

When attempting to install Javabridge I get the following code dump/error message and have no idea where to go from here. I installed a whole bunch of visual studio packages and was able advance the situation from where I was last ([Installing Javabridge With Pip Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48329888/installing-javabridge-with-pip-error)) but have hit a standstill and have found no documentation on where to go from here anywhere online:

```
C:\Users\jmevorach>pip install javabridge
Collecting javabridge
Using cached javabridge-1.0.15.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in 
c:\users\jmevorach\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages 
(from javabridge)
Installing collected packages: javabridge
Running setup.py install for javabridge ... error
Complete output from command 
c:\users\jmevorach\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JMEVOR~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-uden3101\\javabridge\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\JMEVOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-3bjmmnrl-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
 * [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll] Found PE+ image
dlltool: Path components stripped from dllname, 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll'.
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge
copying javabridge\jutil.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge
copying javabridge\locate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge
copying javabridge\noseplugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge
copying javabridge\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge
copying javabridge\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge
copying javabridge\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge\tests
copying javabridge\tests\test_cpython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge\tests
copying javabridge\tests\test_javabridge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge\tests
copying javabridge\tests\test_jutil.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge\tests
copying javabridge\tests\test_wrappers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge\tests
copying javabridge\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge\tests
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge\jars
copying javabridge\jars\cpython.jar -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge\jars
copying javabridge\jars\rhino-1.7R4.jar -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge\jars
copying javabridge\jars\runnablequeue.jar -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge\jars
copying javabridge\jars\test.jar -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge\jars
running build_ext
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javac.exe -source 6 -target 6 C:\Users\JMEVOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uden3101\javabridge\java\org\cellprofiler\runnablequeue\RunnableQueue.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javac.exe -source 6 -target 6 C:\Users\JMEVOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uden3101\javabridge\java\org\cellprofiler\javabridge\test\RealRect.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javac.exe -source 6 -target 6 C:\Users\JMEVOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uden3101\javabridge\java\org\cellprofiler\javabridge\CPython.java C:\Users\JMEVOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uden3101\javabridge\java\org\cellprofiler\javabridge\CPythonInvocationHandler.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
Note: C:\Users\JMEVOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uden3101\javabridge\java\org\cellprofiler\javabridge\CPythonInvocationHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning
building 'javabridge._javabridge' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\jmevorach\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\include\win32" -Ic:\users\jmevorach\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -Ic:\users\jmevorach\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" /Tc_javabridge.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_javabridge.obj
_javabridge.c
c:\users\jmevorach\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
_javabridge.c(4890): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'jobject' to 'int'
_javabridge.c(5211): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'jobject' to 'int'
_javabridge.c(5333): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'jclass' to 'int'
_javabridge.c(5476): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'jmethodID' to 'int'
_javabridge.c(5627): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'jfieldID' to 'int'
_javabridge.c(5992): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'long' to 'jchar', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(6181): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'jfloat', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(7086): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'jint', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(7311): warning C4013: 'CreateJavaVM' undefined; assuming extern returning int
_javabridge.c(7723): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'jint', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(8420): warning C4013: 'StopVM' undefined; assuming extern returning int
_javabridge.c(15042): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'long' to 'jchar', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(15570): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'jfloat', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(17552): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'long' to 'jchar', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(17818): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'long' to 'jchar', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(18346): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'jfloat', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(19095): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'jsize', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(19558): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'jobject' to 'int'
_javabridge.c(19687): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'jobject' to 'int'
_javabridge.c(21593): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'jsize', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(21869): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'jsize', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(22142): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'jsize', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(22415): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'jsize', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(22688): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'jsize', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(22961): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'jsize', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(23234): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'jsize', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(31921): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
_javabridge.c(31927): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\jmevorach\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\include\win32" -Ic:\users\jmevorach\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -Ic:\users\jmevorach\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" /Tc_javabridge_nomac.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_javabridge_nomac.obj
_javabridge_nomac.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\JMEVOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uden3101\javabridge /LIBPATH:c:\users\jmevorach\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\jmevorach\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\lib" jvm.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__javabridge build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_javabridge.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_javabridge_nomac.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge\_javabridge.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_javabridge.cp36-win_amd64.lib
_javabridge.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit__javabridge' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_javabridge.cp36-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_javabridge.cp36-win_amd64.exp
_javabridge_nomac.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM
build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\javabridge\_javabridge.cp36-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

If anyone had any insight as to how I could fix this problem I would greatly appreciate it.